# Добавление новой записи в QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, tableview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ввожу данные в окошко, но по нажатию на кнопку в таблицу добавляется строка с пустыми значениями.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить? Делаю при помощи QDataWidgetMapper.

Форма окна добавления.

```
#include "ui_tripaddform.h"

TripAddForm::TripAddForm(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::TripAddForm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mapper = new QDataWidgetMapper(this);
    mapper->setSubmitPolicy(QDataWidgetMapper::ManualSubmit);
}

TripAddForm::~TripAddForm()
{
    delete ui;
}

void TripAddForm::setModel(QStandardItemModel *model)
{
    mapper->setModel(model);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->trip_name, 0);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->date_from, 1);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->date_to, 2);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->count_wagons, 3);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->count_stop, 4);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->count_tickets, 5);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->count_tickets_sale, 6);
}

void TripAddForm::on_btn_accept_clicked()
{
    mapper->model()->insertRow(mapper->model()->rowCount());
    mapper->setCurrentModelIndex(mapper->model()->index(mapper->model()->rowCount() - 1, 0));

    mapper->submit();
    close();
}
```

Главное окно.

Инициализация
`add_trip = new TripAddForm(this);`

Вызов окна и передача модели.

```
void MainWindow::on_btn_add_trip_clicked()
{
    add_trip->setModel(model_trip);
    add_trip->show();
}
```

Comment: А где модель данных?

Answer (score 1):

К `QTableView` оно не имеет ни какого отношения. Проблема в том, что при

> ```
> mapper->setCurrentModelIndex(mapper->model()->index(mapper->model()->rowCount() - 1, 0));
> ```

все поля ввода перезаписываются данными из модели (пустыми строками), а т.к. далее они ни как не изменяются, то строка так и остаётся пустой.

Выхода 2:

1. Или отказаться от использования `QDataWidgetMapper` и вставлять все данные вручную в конце.
2. Или вставлять пустую строку в модель заранее. Хорошее место, где это можно сделать — перегруженный слот `open()` ( при том, что `TripAddForm` надо унаследовать от `QDialog`). Не забудь также удалить строку при отмене вставки.